# Ruby #to_enum: what's the best way to extract the original object from the enumerator?

Tags: ruby, enumerator

Suppose I have an object:

```
obj = Object.new  #<Object:0x00007fbe36b4db28>
```

And I convert it to an Enumerator:

```
obj_enum = obj.to_enum  #<Enumerator: #<Object:0x00007fbe36b4db28>:each>
```

Now I want to get my object back from the enumerator. I found a way to do it, but it seems unnecessarily abstruse (not to mention pretty fragile):

```
extracted_obj = ObjectSpace._id2ref(
  obj_enum.inspect.match(/0x[0-9a-f]*/).values_at(0)[0].to_i(16)/2
)
p obj.equal? extracted_obj # => true
```

In case it isn't clear, I'm inspecting the Enumerator object, using regex to pull the original object's id from the resulting string, converting it to an integer (and dividing by 2), and using `ObjectSpace._id2ref` to convert the id to a reference to my object. Ugly stuff.

I have trouble believing that this is the easiest way to get this job done, but some hours of googling haven't revealed anything to me. Is there a simple way to extract an object after wrapping an Enumerator around it with `#to_enum`, or is this pretty much the way to do it?

*Edit:*

As Amadan says below (and much appreciated, Amadan), this may be an XY problem, and I may have to rethink my solution. I'll explain a bit about how I got here.

The (meta) use case: I have a (variable) quantity of objects in an array. The objects each expose an array of integers (all of the same size) as an attribute, sorted high to low. I want to iterate the arrays of each of the objects simultaneously, finding the object or objects with the highest integer not matched in another object's array.

It seemed like external iteration was a good way to go about doing this, since simultaneous internal iteration of multiple objects that have to know about the intermediate results of one another's iterations gets out there pretty quickly as well. But when I have found the enumerator that contains the object with the array with the highest value, I need to return the object that it wraps.

There very well may be a better way to go than using enumerators when this is a requirement. However, the actual iteration and selection process is pretty trivial when using them.

So. The applied use case: a quantity of poker hands with no hand better than a high card. Find the winning hand. The "winning hand" is the hand with the highest card not matched in rank by another hand. (Suits are irrelevant.) If all the cards match in two or more hands, return those hands in an array.

"Minimal reproducible example":

```
class Hand
  attr_reader :cards

  def initialize(cards)
    @cards = cards.sort.reverse
  end

  def each
    @cards.each { |card| yield(card.first) }
  end
end

class Poker
  def initialize(hands)
    @hands = hands.map { |hand| Hand.new(hand) }
  end

  def high_cards
    hand_enums = @hands.map(&:to_enum)
    loop do
      max_rank = hand_enums.map(&:peek).max
      hand_enums.delete_if { |enum| enum.peek != max_rank }
      hand_enums.each(&:next)
    end
    hand_enums.map { |e| from_enum(e).cards }
  end

  def from_enum(enum)
    ObjectSpace._id2ref(
      enum.inspect.match(/0x[0-9a-f]*/).values_at(0)[0].to_i(16) / 2
    )
  end
end

hands = [
  [[10, "D"], [3, "C"], [8, "C"], [7, "C"], [9, "D"]],
  [[10, "D"], [8, "S"], [7, "S"], [9, "H"], [2, "H"]],
  [[9, "C"], [8, "H"], [9, "S"], [4, "C"], [7, "D"]]
]

game = Poker.new(hands)
p game.high_cards # => [[[10, "D"], [9, "D"], [8, "C"], [7, "C"], [3, "C"]]]
```

This "works," but I certainly agree with Amadan that it's a hack. An interesting and instructive one, maybe, but a hack all the same. TIA for any suggestions.

Comment: I think you are right, I can't see `Enumerator` expose the wrapped object in any way, except the hack you found. However, even needing to do it is a hack — are you sure there's no other way than get an object from `Enumerator`? Suspecting an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Enumerators don't need an underlying object. `Enumerator.new { |y| y << 1 << 2 << 3 }` creates a perfectly fine enumerator that isn't bound to a specific object.

Comment: Further to @Stefan's point, `1.step` is another example.

Comment: @Amadan That may indeed be the case. I've stepped back and given my thinking process and relevant code in an edit.

Comment: @Stefan Well, that isn't precisely so; your code actually wraps an `Enumerator::Generator` object. (The documentation for the `Enumerator::Generator` object helpfully consists of one word: "Generator," which equally helpfully exposes a link to itself.) But I'm splitting hairs. More to the point, the fact that enumerators can be created without any external object reference (i.e. a reference that you and I can see in our code) to an object doesn't mean that it can't. And the question is about when it is, by using `#to_enum` to wrap an existing object in an enumerator.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm missing you guys' point, I guess. Would you mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: @Stefan was just making the point that not all enumerators are mappings from an underlying object. It doesn't take away from your question; you are looking for the underlying object for an enumerator that has one. For those, I don't believe there is an alternative to your hack.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ok, makes sense. Thank you. And I would appreciate any input on other ways to do the job at hand.

Comment: Why you cannot pass an instance of hand  together with hand enum further and extract it in the end

Comment: @Fabio I've thought about ways to do that, yes. I'm hoping to find a simpler way to go.

Comment: Sorry, I can not understand the logic behind `high_cards` method: Does that mean that if one hand has higher card on first iteration, then other hands will be removed. If so why you need to continue looping other cards of one remained hand? But what if highest card is on another hand but last in the order?

Comment: @Fabio There can be any number of hands in the array, so one could be removed with any number still remaining. I could add logic to break after only one is left, but since there are only five iterations total (and, indeed, there could be some tie hands at the end), it seemed less efficient to add that check on each iteration.

Comment: @Stefan My comment sounds a bit dismissive after looking at it again. Please excuse me if it does to you as well; I didn't mean that.

Comment: Sorry again, does collection of cards on hand always ordered in descending order?

Comment: @Fabio Yes, I set it up that way.

Comment: What about a method like this `get_highest_hand(hands)` and internally within that method, you would iterate through all the cards held by the respective hands?

Comment: @BobRodes I just wanted to point out that enumerators aren't necessarily backed by a collection. Just like IO-like objects aren't necessarily file based. Think of an enumerator as something that yields objects in a specific order, nothing more, nothing less. Let's say these objects are characters. Their source could be a string within the code or a file on a harddisk or maybe interactive user input. Our fictitious character enumerator adds an abstraction layer and deliberately hides those details.

Comment: @Stefan If you take your code and inspect the resulting enumerator, though, it would seem that it is backed by an `Enumerator::Generator` object. Isn't that a collection? I'm seeing the Enumerator object as a wrapper for another object that iterates through the internal object in accordance with whatever that object yields to iterate.

Comment: @BobRodes `Enumerator::Generator` seems to be a wrapper around the block given to `Enumerator.new` so that `Enumerator` can deal with an object having an `each` method. But those are implementation details. Enumerators don't expose their sources, they just yield values.

Comment: @Stefan Yes, I'm seeing that. If you want to get an enumerator to expose its source you have to hack into it, and that is a fragile thing to do.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Not sure of the distinction you're drawing. Isn't that what `high_cards` is doing now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why all this talk of enums.

I'll presume hands are in a format similar to this:

```
hands = [Hand.new([[12, "H"], [10, "H"], [8, "D"], [3, "D"], [2, "C"]]),
         Hand.new([[10, "D"], [9, "H"], [3, "C"], [2, "D"], [2, "H"]]),
         Hand.new([[12, "D"], [10, "S"], [8, "C"], [3, "S"], [2, "H"]]),
         Hand.new([[12, "C"], [9, "S"], [8, "C"], [8, "S"], [8, "S"]])]
```

and you want to get the 0th and 2nd element. I'll also assume the hands are sorted, per your assert. As far as I can see, this is all that is needed, since arrays compare lexicographically:

```
max_ranks = hands.map { |hand| hand.cards.map(&:first) }.max
max_hands = hands.select { |hand| hand.cards.map(&:first) == max_ranks }
```

Alternately, use `group_by` (a bit better, as it doesn't need to calculate ranks twice):

```
hands_by_ranks = hands.group_by { |hand| hand.cards.map(&:first) }
max_hands = hands_by_ranks[hands_by_ranks.keys.max]
```

Comment: Apologies. It's very late right now, so I will wait to post a reproducible example. But this isn't exactly correct. In the example you give, the first iteration would eliminate the 1st element, and then the second iteration would eliminate the (now) 1st element, since 9 is less than 10. Same as you would in poker, if all the ranks in each hand were different. (In your example, of course, there is a pair in the second hand and three of a kind in the third.)

Comment: This is why I said you don't have a [example]. If you make one, I will revisit. Assume I don't know anything about poker: explain everything.

Comment: _and you want to get the 0th and 2nd element, because 12 is highest_ - not quite so, you want to get only 0-th element, because hand (12, 10, 8, 3, 2) has higher rank than 2-nd element (12, 9, 8, 8, 8). 12 == 12 but 10 > 9

Comment: Corrected to @Fabio's clarification and OP's class definition.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, there is no way to reliably retrieve the underlying object, because the enumerator doesn't always have one.
While your solution will work for this specific case, I would suggest coming up with another approach that will not depend on the implementation details of the enumerator object.

One of the possible solutions would be to pass an instance of `Hand` along with the enumerator.

```
class Poker
  def high_cards(hands)
    hand_enums = hands.map { |hand| [hand, hand.to_enum] }

    loop do
      max_rank = hand_enums.map(&:last).map(&:peek).max
      hand_enums.delete_if {|enum| enum.last.peek != max_rank }

      hand_enums.each {|pair| pair.last.next}
    end

    hand_enums.map(&:first)
  end
end
```

Another more object-oriented approach is to introduce a custom `Enumerator` and expose the underlying object in a more explicit way:

```
class HandEnumerator < Enumerator
  attr_reader :hand

  def initialize(hand, &block)
    @hand = hand
    super(block)
  end
end

class Hand
  def to_enum
    HandEnumerator.new(self) { |yielder| @cards.each { |card| yielder << card.first }}
  end

  # To satisfy interface of enumerator creation
  def enum_for 
    to_enum
  end
end

class Poker
  def high_cards(hands)
    hand_enums = hands.map(&:to_enum)

    loop do
      max_rank = hand_enums.map(&:peek).max
      hand_enums.delete_if {|enum| enum.peek != max_rank }

      hand_enums.each(&:next)
    end

    hand_enums.map(&:hand)
  end
end
```

Comment: I like this. I had thought about doing something like it, but was pretty burned out at the time and didn't see a way to do it easily. I also take your point about dependency on the implementation details of the enumerator; it's what was bothering me about this in the first place. (p.s. in a purely technical sense, the enumerator *does* always have an underlying object that it wraps, as you can see for yourself if you create a few in a few different ways and use `#inspect` to see the results. In this I disagree with the other comments, although I can agree with them in a practical sense.)

Comment: I like your additional (OO) idea even more. :) Very nice. Thanks for sharing it. Before I accept this as the answer, I'd like to dig into your `Hand#to_enum` so I fully understand it. I don't have time to do that today, but I will do it tomorrow. (p.s. I corrected `#for_enum` to `#enum_for` — after looking it up to be sure.)

Comment: Fabio, I've dug into your code and have a better understanding of it now. I had never seen anything like your `yielder << card.first`, and have some questions about it. Why do you put this instead of `yielder.yield card.first`? Are they equivalent? If so, that suggests to me that the (undocumented) `Enumerator::Yielder` object is an array. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: `yield` and `<<` both doing same thing, only difference is that `<<` will return self(yielder) back to the caller. I have no preferences between those two. `<<` easier to use in `reduce` method, because it returns yielder to the next iteration. Yielder is not an array, but _A simple class which allows the construction of Enumerator from a block_ (from source code comments :))