# In Ruby is an Enumerable's yielder similar to yield in any way?

Tags: ruby, yield, control-flow, enumerable

I am trying to grok the difference between a regular use of `yield` in a function and the `yielder` one uses with an Enumerable.

By a regular use of `yield` I mean:

```
def fun
  yield
end

fun do
  puts "hello"
end
```

And by the Enumerator's yielder I mean:

```
def fun2
  Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    (0..2).each { |x| yielder << x }
  end
end

fun2.each do |x|
  puts x
end
```

How can I succinctly understand the difference between `yield` and `yielder` in terms of control flow and other relevant differences? Are they even comparable? Or is the yielder not really related to `yield` despite the naming?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071802/when-is-the-enumeratoryielderyield-method-useful

Comment: I got into a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60073714/ruby-to-enum-whats-the-best-way-to-extract-the-original-object-from-the-enume) on this as well that might be helpful.